# How to support Command in REST while doing REST, CQRS and EventSourcing together?

Tags: api, rest, cqrs, event-sourcing

Consider the following coarse grained REST apis for a Contact resource

```
POST          /api/contacts                             
GET           /api/contacts                             
GET           /api/contacts/:id                         
PUT           /api/contacts/:id                         
DELETE        /api/contacts/:id
```

Consider using eventsourcing for the contact resource, i.e. commands are validated and events are stored. So every event must be stored, including each field level change.

```
CreateContactCommand -> | Contact("john", "doe", 25) | -> ContactCreatedEvent
FirstNameChangeCommand -> | Contact("jane", "doe", 25) | -> FirstNameChangedEvent
LastNameChangeCommand -> | Contact("jane", "dear", 25) | -> LastNameChangedEvent
AgeChangeCommand -> | Contact("jane", "doe", 30) | -> AgeChangedEvent
```

Now, combining REST and EventSourcing both.

Doing REST, how the client communicates to the above standard REST APIs for field level changes to generate commands at server side REST end point?

Major question is, how to design REST API so that it can also support the commands eventually supporting eventsourcing?

If anybody could shed light on this, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30074785/126014

Comment: Is there a special reason for screaming at us (writing in bold)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CQRS and event Sourcing is neither an API design principle, nor is it a top-level architecture. Still, if you want to 'expose' your API as a *task-based API*, you can expose links as part of the *contact* resource.

```
GET /contacts/1234
```

Response

```
200 OK
<contact>
  <atom:link href="/contacts/1234/first-name" rel="first-name" />
  <atom:link href="/contacts/1234/last-name" rel="last-name" />
  <atom:link href="/contacts/1234/age" rel="age" />
  <first-name>Jane</first-name>
  <last-name>Doe</last-name>
  <age>25</age>
</contact>
```

The assumption here is that you change the API to a **true** [level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) REST API.

Also, `/contacts/1234` will only accept `GET` and `DELETE` (*not* `PUT`) requests. If a client wants to change e.g. the first name of a contact, it must follow a link with the relationship type `first-name` and make a `PUT` request against that resource:

```
PUT /contacts/1234/first-name
<first-name>John</first-name>
```

Anything else than a `first-name` field `PUT` here should be ignored or rejected.

Thus, when the service receives a `PUT` against a *first-name* resource, it's a command to change the first name of the contact.

This still isn't a proper *task-based API* because it doesn't capture *why* the first name changes, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Mark for clicking the idea. It will help me get started.

Comment: +1 to "This isn't a proper task-based UI". Chances are your commands and events are much too granular for your system's own sanity.

Comment: So if you need to change the first and last name you have to produce 2 requests? Also, you have to handle each of this request separately. Writing generic handler will lead you to the implementation of kind of PATCH method... Looks at least strange.

Comment: @Savash This post is mostly about DDD, CQRS, and *task-based APIs*. As I remarked in my answer, the example isn't really *task-based*, but I was attempted to get a point across in a digestible manner. It's not really about changing the first name or the last name, but about providing information about *why* things change. If you have a reason to change both first name and last name, you could provide a semantic link for that as well, but keep in mind that this isn't CRUD.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Don't you think that the properties that should be changed together are usually grouped into the models and creating the semantic links for that lead us to the same REST?

Comment: @Savash That's one of Kent Beck's rules of thumb: _things that change together should go together; things that change at different rates should not_... (paraphrasing from memory).

Answer (score 0):

REST is a distributed applicative architectural style for the Web. The Web has its own rules and constraints, it's a realm of representations and resources, not tasks, commands or queries.

The Web is lower level than your application. When designing your HTTP resources, you have to think about caching, versioning, repeatability, performance, loose coupling in a Web context, so you might not want to make them match domain entities exactly, *let alone properties of these entities*. In addition, HTTP has a very limited number of verbs, and when verbs fail you, resources are not necessarily the best choice to describe a task or an action.

Therefore, a strict one-to-one correspondence between the commands that make sense in your domain and a (resource, verb) couple isn't always desirable or adequate. You may want to go further and design your own Domain Application Protocol for REST clients to talk to the server according to finer rules. A DAP is reflected in hypermedia links and relationships for transitions, as Mark pointed out, but you can also use custom content-types to better describe the type of payload in requests or responses. They could, for instance, contain the type of domain command you're sending.

If you look at [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-api-on-cqrs), you'll see that the (`POST`, `api/inventoryItem/{id}`) couple isn't unique in the chart under "Resources". It can be used to transport either a `RemoveItemsFromInventoryCommand` or a `CheckInItemsToInventoryCommand`. How you specify that at an HTTP request level is by using a custom content type header : `Content-Type:application/json;domain-model=RemoveItemsFromInventoryCommand` or `Content-Type:application/json;domain-model=CheckInItemsToInventoryCommand`.

Comment: Hi guillaume31,

I think I am also getting a chance to clear. For designing DAP, is it good to expose the behaviour of resource in such way as in the article you mentioned? or follow the level 3 REST API design as Mark pointed out?

Should I choose the way that is easier for me?

Comment: The article also describes a level 3 REST API. Everything Mark said remains valid. The thing is, your commands don't capture user intent (*task-based UI*) IMO. They are very granular, going down to the field level. Thus you're forced to either shoehorn every single entity field into a resource, which I find impractical, or find another way, for instance through media types. But both would remain level 3 on the Richardson REST maturity model.

Comment: Putting a command name in the URL or in the Content-Type header, how is it different ? Neither are about transferring state.

Comment: @arnaud576875 it's different because putting a command name in a URI would mean it's a different resource. Besides, REST isn't about transferring state but transferring *representations* that *capture the current or intended state of that resource*. And of course the examples I give capture the intended state. Their payload contains a bit of the future state of the resource, namely `{ count: X }`.

Comment: @arnaud576875 but surely you can share with us your own ideal solution to the problem ?

Comment: What about specifying the command type in a custom header? Would that be acceptable? Are there any major shortcomings?