# Event sourcing and validation on writes

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Still pretty young at ES and CQRS, I understand that they are tightly related to eventual consistency of data.

Eventual consistency can be problematic when we should perform validation before writing to the store, like checking that an email address isn't already used by an existing user. The only way to do that in a strongly consistent way would be to stop accepting new events, finish processing the remaining events against our view and then querying the view. We obviously don't want to go that far and Greg Young actually [recommends](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/) to embrace eventual consistency and deal with (rare) cases where we break constraints.

Pushing this approach to the limits, my understanding is that this would mean, when developing a web API for example, to respond 'OK' to every request because it is impossible, at the time of the request, to validate it... Am I on the right track, or missing something here?

Comment: A RESTful API can return `202 Accepted` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30078502/126014

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I like how this approach makes the system less 'smoky' from the client's view, although the 'status monitoring' requires maintaining a history of commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in my comment above, [a RESTful API can return `202 Accepted`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30078502/126014).

This provides a way for a client to poll for status updates if that's necessary.

The client *can* monitor for state if that's desirable, but alternatively, it can also simply fire and forget, assuming that if it gets *any* sort of `200`-range response, the command will *eventually* be applied. This can be a good alternative if you have an alternative channel on which you can propagate errors. For example, if you know which user submitted the command, and you have that user's email address, you can send an email in the event of a failure to apply the command.

One of the points of a CQRS architecture is that the edge of the system should do whatever it can to validate the correctness of a Command before it accepts it. Based on the known state of the system (as exposed by the Query side), the system can make a strong effort to validate that a given Command is acceptable. If it does that, the only permanent error that should happen if you accept a Command is a concurrency conflict. Depending on how fast your system approaches consistent states, such concurrency conflicts may be so few that e.g. sending the user an email is an appropriate error-handling strategy.